# iOS: how to debug kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure

Tags: macos, openssl, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, keychain

I have read quite a few posts and sources now but couldn't find a definite answer.

I'm getting `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure` on my `SecTrustEvaluate()` call and I would like to figure out why this is so (i.e. I want to figure out where exactly the trust chain validation fails and why). on OSX there seem to be some related function called `SecTrustGetResult`, but this is deprecated now even on OSX

How can I figure out where the validation fails? i'm fine with using private API's as I'm using this only during debugging to understand what exactly is going on inside.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use `SecTrustCopyProperties()` after calling `SecTrustEvaluate()`:

```
SecTrustRef trust = ...;
SecTrustResultType trustResult = kSecTrustResultOtherError;
OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {
    NSArray * trustProperties = (__bridge_transfer id)
        SecTrustCopyProperties(certTrust);
}
```

`trustProperties` is an array of dictionaries, one dictionary per cert in the cert chain evaluated. Every dictionary has an entry `title`, containing the name of the cert and if the cert didn't evaluate, it also contains an entry `error` containing the error. E.g. if the problem was that the cert has expired, the value of `error` will be `CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED`.